# Error uploading data to firestore using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

Im new to swift and have been following some tutorials on how to upload data to google firestore and so im using this code upload my data:

```
func firestoreSubmit_data(docRef_string:String, dataToSave:[String: Any], completion: @escaping (Any) -> Void){
let docRef = Firestore.firestore().document(docRef_string)
print("setting data")
docRef.setData(dataToSave){ (error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("error = \(error)")
        completion(error)
    } else {
        print("data uploaded successfully")
        
    }
}
```

and using this code to call the function:

```
firestoreSubmit_data(docRef_string: "recipe/\(thisRecipePost.id)", dataToSave: thisRecipePost.dictionary, completion: {_ in})
```

However when I run it, it produces this error:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: __SwiftValue'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

[see error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChtRt.png)

Does anyone know a work around or fix to this issue?

Edit:

```
let thisRecipePost = RecipePost(steps: self.steps,
                                                        ingredients: self.ingredients,
                                                        postingUser: self.env.currentUser.establishedID,
                                                        description: "",
                                                        numberOfLikes: 0,
                                                        image: Image(uiImage: self.images[0].image)
```

I also created a struct for recipePost which looks likes like this:

```
struct RecipePost: Identifiable{
var id = UUID()
var steps: [Step]
var ingredients: [Ingredient]
var postingUser: String
var description: String
var numberOfLikes: Int
var image: Image

var dictionary: [String: Any]{ 
    return [
        "id": id.uuidString,
        "steps": steps.formatForFirebase(),
        "ingredients": ingredients.formatForFirebase(),
        "postingUser": postingUser,
        "description": description,
        "numberOfLikes": numberOfLikes
    ]
}
```

}

Format for firebase function:

```
extension Array where Element == Step {
func formatForFirebase() -> [[String:Any]]{
    var returnVal:[[String:Any]] = []
    for element in self {
        returnVal.append(element.dictionary)
    }
    
    return returnVal
}
```

}

```
extension Array where Element == Ingredient {
func formatForFirebase() -> [[String:Any]]{
    var returnVal:[[String:Any]] = []
    for element in self {
        returnVal.append(element.dictionary)
    }
    
    return returnVal
}
```

}

Comment: Can you include your definition of thisRecipePost.dictionary i.e. what data types are being used? It looks like you might be passing in an NSMutableString which is not supported.

Comment: Hey, I've just updated my post to include 'thisRecipePost', I've also added the struct I created called RecipePost.

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional context around 'thisRecipePost'. Can you also add in the code for steps.formatForFirebase() and ingredients.formatForFirebase()?

Comment: Both methods for the formatforfirebase have now been added

Comment: Thanks for adding! Double-check your definitions of step and ingredient because you're most likely passing in an unsupported data type there (see my answer below for the firestore documentation). Casting to [String: Any] doesn't mean the data types are necessarily valid.

Comment: The documentation below has really helped out, im getting a few other errors here and there but I think ill be able to fix those. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is indicating that an unsupported data type is being passed in. Double-check the data types in your dict (including steps.formatForFirebase() and ingredients.formatForFirebase()) and make sure they're listed here: [firestore supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).